# Postgresql database disappeared after changing 'localhost' to local IP address

Tags: postgresql

In pgAdmin4, I have changed my server's connection address to my machine's IP address (changed from localhost), and while some dbs are still there, one isn't.

Do you know how can I get it back?

Thanks.

PostgreSQL 10.4

EDIT: Here is the pg_hba.conf  https://pastebin.com/wb3wL35U

EDIT2: Also, in poistgresql.conf, if I set listen_addresses = 'localhost' I get the:

**could not bind IPv4 address "127.0.0.1": Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.**

If I revert it to: **listen_addresses = '*'** database server starts.

Comment: Discussion on this question has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78915/discussion-on-question-by-savo-pejovic-postgresql-database-disappeared-after-cha).